# How to align words in dropdownlist option

Tags: css, alignment

Is there a way to align 3 words in a dropdownlist option ?
eg.

```
<option value="1">ABCDE - ALPHA</option
<option value="2">1234 - NUMERIC</option>
<option value="3">ABC123 - ALPHANUMERIC</option>
```

I want the outcome of above to be

```
ABCDE  - ALPHA
1234   - NUMERIC
ABC123 - ALPHANUMERIC
```

instead of

```
ABCDE - ALPHA
1234 - NUMERIC
ABC123 - ALPHANUMERIC
```

is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any possible help

Comment: Use monospacing font in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'd need to use a [*monospace* font-family](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#monospace-def) and add the extra spacing in yourself. As two space characters will be rendered as one, you'll need to use non-breaking space character entities (`&nbsp;`) instead of just extra spaces:

#### HTML

```
<select>
    <option value="1">ABCDE - ALPHA</option>
    <option value="2">1234 &nbsp;- NUMERIC</option>
</select>
```

#### CSS

```
select {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/b28sw/).

Comment: so that would work for 2 data what if i have more than that? lets say a loop and dun noe the exact char of the first word so how do i cater for that? Thnks!

Comment: @user2435903 in that case you'd have to use JavaScript to loop through each `option` to find the one with the greatest number of characters before the " - " and add `&nbsp;` characters accordingly. To me this seems a bit overkill for a simple `select` element. Why don't you just use `12345` alongside `ABCDE`?

Comment: this is just an example. My data is rather huge and im using loop to generate the values. great! is there any example with the use of javascript for that?